# NaN values created when joining two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to one hot encode data using the sci-kit learn library from, kaggle https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/rkiattisak/salaly-prediction-for-beginer

[image: kaggle data]

X is a two column dataframe of the age and years of experience columns with the rows containing null values cleaned out with `dropna()`. My goal is to one hot encode the Gender and Education columns and merge the one hot encoded values with the values in X. Here are X and df_one pre-join:

[image: X and df_one pre-Join]

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
myTransformer = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[('one_hot_encoder', OneHotEncoder(), ['Gender', 'Education Level'])],
)
transformed = myTransformer.fit_transform(X)
columns = myTransformer.named_transformers_['one_hot_encoder'].get_feature_names_out(['Gender', 'Education Level']).tolist()
df_ohe = pd.DataFrame(transformed, columns=columns)
display(df_ohe)
print(df_ohe.isnull().sum())
X = X.drop(columns=['Gender', 'Education Level'])
display(X)
print(X.isnull().sum())
X = X.join(df_ohe)
print(X.isnull().sum())
X
```

Before I ran the transformer, I cleaned my data so that all rows with NaN values were removed using the `dropna()` function, and using the `.isnull().sum()` method I was able to confirm that there were no null values left. Debugging also confirmed that there are no null values in df_ohe, the one hot encoded dataframe. Printing the isnull sum confirms that two rows contain NaN values for the one hot encoded columns once X has been joined with df_ohe. After the join the data is as below:
[image: post-join]

Does anyone know why this might be happening or if there's a better/safer way to join these dataframes?

Comment: It will be hard to debug without an example dataset. We don't know what you are trying to one hot encode. If you had a small example with one or two rows and a few columns that would help.

Comment: @ASimpleProgrammer I updated the question with a link to the kaggle data.

Comment: @ASimpleProgrammer I just added some examples to visualize what I was describing as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you were trying to do. I think the problem  was the indexes were different between the dataframes you were merging. You can reset the index and then merge them together like I do below.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
import pandas as pd

X = pd.read_csv('Salary Data.csv')
X = X.dropna()

ohe_vars = ['Gender', 'Education Level']
OHE_X = X[ohe_vars]
myTransformer = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[('one_hot_encoder',
                   OneHotEncoder(),
                   ohe_vars)],
)
transformed = myTransformer.fit_transform(OHE_X)
columns = myTransformer \
    .named_transformers_['one_hot_encoder'] \
    .get_feature_names_out(ohe_vars) \
    .tolist()
df_ohe = pd.DataFrame(transformed, columns=columns)
df_ohe.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
X.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(df_ohe.shape)
print(X.shape)
new_df = X.join(df_ohe)
print(new_df.shape)
```

Comment: I showed no nulls in the new_df with `new_df.isnull().sum()`